# Laravel group by if there is no row, return zero

Tags: php, laravel

I am listing last 16 days num of views. I want to write 0; if there is not row at date:

```
$digital_case_daily_views = DB::table('digital_case_views')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as numOfDigitalCaseViews'))->groupBy('created_at')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(16)->get();
```

laravel 5.6

it returns like:

```
    "digital_case_daily_views": [
        {
            "numOfDigitalCaseViews": 162
        },
        {
            "numOfDigitalCaseViews": 458
        },
        {
            "numOfDigitalCaseViews": 287
        },
        {
            "numOfDigitalCaseViews": 1
        },
        {
            "numOfDigitalCaseViews": 1
        },
        {
            "numOfDigitalCaseViews": 1
        }
```

Comment: The main problem is when you don't have a single record of a particular day then you don't have record for that day so you can't set zero directly

Comment: @SagarGautam i got it, i return created_at parameter with count. Everything is ok now. I ll set zero in backend process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get more rows from the database than available, if you want to have 0 for the remaining days, you have to add them to the array, I've written a function for you that might help you with this:

```
class Foo {
    static public function addRemainingDays(array $arr, int $amount) {
        if(count($arr) === $amount) {
            return $arr;
        }

        for($i = 0; i > $amount - count($arr); i++) {
            array_push($arr, (object)["numOfDigitalCaseViews" => 0]);
        }

        return $arr
    }
}
```